# Show employee details with thumbnail image of employee in modal popup extender varbinary

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
 <asp:GridView CssClass="table table-bordered" ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
  BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" DataKeyNames="id">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Container.DataItemIndex +1 %>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Empid" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="age" HeaderText="Age" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="position" HeaderText="Position" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="state" HeaderText="State" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="postalcode" HeaderText="Pin Code" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="country" HeaderText="Country" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile" HeaderText="Mobile" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Alternate Phone" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("profilepic")!=DBNull.Value%>' ImageUrl='<%#Eval("profilepic")!=DBNull.Value ? "data:Image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("profilepic")) : string.Empty%>' Height="50px" Width="50px"
        />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="LinkButton4_Click" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" ImageUrl="~/images/save.png" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Update" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
      </EditItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

  </Columns>

  <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066"></FooterStyle>

  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

  <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066"></PagerStyle>

  <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066"></RowStyle>

  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></SelectedRowStyle>
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9">
  </SortedDescendingCellStyle>
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E">
  </SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
  <div class="header">
    Details
  </div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Age</th>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Address</th>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>State</th>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Postal Code</th>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Alternate Phone</th>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="footer" align="right">
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="button" />
  </div>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Button ID="buttonshowpop1" runat="server" Text="Button" style="display:none" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" TargetControlID="buttonshowpop1" PopupControlID="Panel1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

I want to display employee details in modal pop up extender ajax I have binary image saved in varbinary max through upload file in inserts employees in SQL Server database table. I have searched but cannot find related to this

Comment: So what is your question? What are you stuck on?

Comment: i have inserted a image in sql database table as binary i have to show in modal popup but i dont know  how to display image in modal pop up

Comment: Right, but you do know how to retrieve the image from your database?

Comment: yes i know how to display in gridview but in modal popup i cannot display

Comment: I tried gto format your code wall but it is still a mess IMHO; moving on

Comment: Sorry but I am new in coding and I am learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one `ModalPopupExtender` for employee detail, then move the control to `ItemTemplate`. Then create a pop up panel `DetailsPopUpPanel` to show an enlarged version of the image with additional employee details. Finally wire up everything using properties. So when user clicks on `ViewDetailsButton`, the `DetailsPopUpPanel` comes up.

```aspx
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ViewDetailsButton" Visible='<%#Eval("profilepic")!=DBNull.Value%>' runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("profilepic")!=DBNull.Value ? "data:Image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("profilepic")) : string.Empty%>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
    <asp:Panel ID="DetailsPopUpPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none">
        <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%#Eval("profilepic")!=DBNull.Value ? "data:Image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("profilepic")) : string.Empty%>' width="800" height="400" runat="server" />
        <div style="text-align:center;">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ClosePopUpPanel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/x.png" Width="25px" />
            </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID="ViewDetailsButton" PopupControlID='DetailsPopUpPanel' CancelControlID="ClosePopUpPanel" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```